# Find Top date By Desending Order in postgresSql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i only want latest orderDate By userId  from OrderPayment table where identifier='M' and PaymentStatus=succesfull[enter image description here.Please guide me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER2BD.png)

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, is your question around the exact query needed to perform the above task or are you facing issue with using JPA for performing this?
(The question is tagged under spring-data-jpa but in the question you just asked about the database challenge so wanted to make sure).

Comment: i used spring data jpa but i want exact query .